# Time Complexity with Strings in Python

Tags: python

this may have been asked before. However I'm unable to find an answer by searching, as I may just be searching the wrong thing.

I have two similar functions, with one minor difference. From timing them both, one is significantly faster than the other.

The below function takes a word list, and concatenates each word. You'll noticed there's a line `temp = concat` which doesn't need to be there.

```
def concat_with_add(word_list):
    concat = ''
    for word in word_list:
        concat += word
        temp = concat
    return concat
```

This function is the same as above, only `temp = concat` is not removed. This function is significantly faster.

```
def concat_with_add(word_list):
    concat = ''
    for word in word_list:
        concat += word
    return concat
```

I read an explanation to this, but struggled to wrap my head around why assigning the `concat` variable to a `temp` variable would slow things down so drastically. Is anyone able to explain this in a way I'd understand?

Edit: This is how I'm timing it -

```
import time

start = time.time()
concat_with_add(random_strings)
end = time.time()
time_add = end - start
    
print(time_add)
```

Length of word list is 100,000

Time it takes with `temp = concat` is: **4.5**

Time without it is: **.02**

Comment: How are you timing them and how big is this `word_list`?

Comment: Hi. I've edited my question to add some additional info. I'm just wondering why it's so much slower when `temp = concat` is added

Comment: @ggorlen `temp = concat` indeed doesn't perform a copy, but `concat += word` does (in the sense that `concat`'s contents are copied to a new string together with the contents of `word`). This copy can be optimized away if there are no other references to the string, so that's why introducing a second reference with `temp = concat` makes the code slower: it prevents that optimization.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Semantically the line `concat += word` creates a new string containing the concatenation of `concat` and `word` and then re-assigns `concat` to refer to that new string. This would make the runtime of your loop quadratic because creating this new string takes time linear in the lengths of both `concat` and `word`.

However, in the actual implementation CPython optimizes this to mutate the contents of `concat` instead of creating a new string *if and only if* `concat` is the only reference to the string. Appending to a string in-place takes time that is only linear in the length of `word` (amortized). This makes the runtime of your loop linear. But, as I said, this optimization can only be applied if `concat` is the only reference to the string (otherwise the value of other variables would change as well, which would break the semantics). So introducing another reference to the string with `temp = concat` prevents the optimization.

Comment: Ah thank you. I'm starting to understand now. I think what I'm still struggling with is why the value of other variables changing would break the semantics? I may just need re-read what you wrote a few times before I get it.

Comment: @AaronWright Let's say you do this: `str = "hello"; temp = str; str += " world"`. The semantics of Python are such that this will cause `str` to equal "hello world" and `temp` to equal "hello". In other words, changing `str` after the `temp = str` assignment should not change `temp` as well (because strings are immutable). So if an optimization did make it so that `temp` changed as well, that would break Python's semantics - it would make it behave differently than its own rules say it should.

Comment: Ah okay, yep I get it now. Perfect. Thanks for the assistance!